# Condición con valor único sin repetir SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, A.HORA), 'hh:mm tt') AS HORA,
IIF ((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA)) <= B.MONTO_EMISION, '','X') AS SEL,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.TASA) + '%' AS  TASA,
    '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA)) AS MONEY),1)) AS ACUM1,
    IIF ((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA)) <= B.MONTO_EMISION, '$' + FORMAT((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA)),'#,0.00'),'0') AS ACUM2
FROM TBITACORA A
    INNER JOIN TDASHBOARD B ON A.REF = B.REF
    WHERE A.REF = 1
    ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA
```

Dando el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que SEL marque con una X unicamente en la primer Tasa Máxima cuando ACUM2 sea 0 ?, como la tengo me marca todas las tasas máximas al ser ACUM2 cero.

La BD TBITACORA esta conformada de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la consulta completa es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
            A.REF AS REF,
            A.POSTURA AS POSTURA,
            FORMAT(A.FECHA, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS FECHA,
            FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, A.HORA), 'hh:mm tt') AS HORA,
            A.TIPO AS TIPO,
            A.MEDIO AS MEDIO,
            A.RECIBIO AS RECIBIO,
            A.CLIENTE AS CLIENTE,
            '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(A.VALOR_OFRECIDO AS MONEY),1)) AS VALOR_OFRECIDO,
            '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO AS MONEY),1)) AS MONTO_SOLICITADO,
            '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(A.MONTO_ASIGNAR AS MONEY),1)) AS MONTO_ASIGNAR,
            IIF((SELECT MAX(TASA) FROM TBITACORA WHERE REF = $REF) = A.TASA, 'X' , '') AS SEL,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.TASA) + '%' AS  TASA,
            '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA)) AS MONEY),1)) AS ACUM1,
            IIF ((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA)) <= B.MONTO_EMISION, '$' + FORMAT((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA)),'#,0.00'),'0') AS ACUM2,
            A.SINDICACION AS SINDICACION,
            A.PROMOTOR AS PROMOTOR,
            A.CONTRATO AS CONTRATO,
            A.OBS AS OBS,
            A.CAPTURADA AS CAPTURADA
            FROM TBITACORA A
            INNER JOIN TDASHBOARD B ON A.REF = B.REF
            WHERE A.REF = $REF
            GROUP BY A.REF, A.POSTURA, A.FECHA, A.HORA, A.TIPO, A.MEDIO, A.RECIBIO, A.CLIENTE, A.VALOR_OFRECIDO, A.MONTO_SOLICITADO, A.MONTO_ASIGNAR, A.TASA, B.MONTO_EMISION, A.SINDICACION, A.PROMOTOR, A.CONTRATO, A.OBS, A.CAPTURADA
            ORDER BY A.TASA, A.HORA
```

Está ordenado por Tasa y por hora para que nos pueda dar de menor a mayor la Tasa y también lo ordene por hora. Pego el ejemplo de como debería quedar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde SEL marca con una X la primer tasa mayor y donde acum2 da cero la cual condiciona de la siguiente manera:

ACUM2 = Si Acum1 <= 1,000,000,000 entonces Acum1 si no 0

P.D. La consulta en general funciona a excepción de marcar la primer tasa mayor y cuando ACUM2 es 0 en ordenamiento a Tasa y Hora.

### Gracias

Gracias a Edgar Vazquez, les comento que Acum1 es la suma acumulada de Monto Solicitado y Acum2 esta condicionado; significa que si la suma acumulado de Monto Solicitado es menor o igual a Monto Emision entonces que continúe sumando el acumulado cuando ya no sea menor o igual coloque 0.

Todo esto significa que Acum1 y Acum2 no son columnas dentro de la tabla y las calculo al vuelo por lo que con el apoyo de Edgar, Sel lo calcule con Row_Number() sobre la tasa que sea mayor y si es = 1 entonces coloque X de lo contrario '':

```
IIF((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.TASA DESC)) = 1,'X','') AS SEL,
```

el resto del código no cambia. SOLUCIONADO

Comment: Podrías usar un ROW_NUMBER para generar números cuando acum2 sea 0 y ah ese primero con un case lo validas y le asignas el valor.

Comment: Podrías orientarme un poco más por favor, no logro cachar la idea. Gracias

Comment: Tendrias el script de tu tabla y algunos registros para insertar para que te apoye con el script

Comment: Gracias, edito la consulta.

Comment: Te falto la de tdash por que veo que le haces JOIN

Comment: El join es para traer el monto emision de otra tabla a través de la referencia, pero el monto emisión en este caso cuando REF es igual 1 equivale a 1,000,000,000

Comment: $REF = 1, ahí lo tengo como variable porque a través de php le asigno el valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te anexo lo que realice para ver si con eso te ayudo un poco mas, en el primer CTE tendrías lo que tu ya tienes pero sin el SEL, en el segundo CTE tendrías el ROW_NUMBER que te comente para que ahí formemos los números.

Y al final evaluamos el 0 que comentas que evalúas y que sea el primero.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
Tasa DECIMAL(18,2),
ACUM1  DECIMAL(18,2),
ACUM2  DECIMAL(18,2)
)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(0.3,758763300.00,758763300.00)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(0.35,821263300.00,821263300)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(0.36,1021263300.00,0.00)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(0.36,1021263300.00,0.00)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(0.36,1021263300.00,0.00)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(0.36,1021263300.00,0.00)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(0.36,1021263300.00,0.00)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(0.36,1021263300.00,0.00)

;WITH CTE_ AS (
--AQUI VA TU SELECT NORMAL SIN LA VARIABLE SEL
--YO HAGO UN SELECT FROM PARA SIMULAR EL RESULTADO DEL CTE
SELECT * FROM @Table
),
CTE_SEL AS (

   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACUM2 ORDER BY ACUM2 DESC) AS RN,*
   FROM CTE_
)
SELECT CASE WHEN RN=1 AND ACUM2=0 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END SEL,Tasa,ACUM1,ACUM2 
FROM CTE_SEL
ORDER BY ACUM2 DESC
```

Te anexo una url donde lo puedes ejecutar y jugar con el si deseas para entender que hace.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ebebbdbf83f8b947939d0fe73283d3f

Te anexo información sobre los CTE por si no los conoces, el ROW_NUMBER imagino que si ya que veo que lo usas.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15